# How do I make SwiftUI show entire vertical content on iPad?

Tags: swiftui

I have a SwiftUI application that was laid out using an iPhone. Now when I run it on an iPad, it appears to fill the entire width of the screen, but much of the view content is cutoff on the top and bottom. The top level view contains a container (which can hold any number of different views, based on navigation) and a splash view, which times out after the animation. Is there a way to tell it to honor the size required to fit all of the vertical views, and auto-size the width?
This is the top level view. I can post more, but that is a lot of code.

```
import SwiftUI
struct ContentView: View {

    @State var showSplash = true

    var body: some View {
        ZStack() {
            ContainerView()
            SplashView()
              .opacity(showSplash ? 1 : 0)
              .onAppear {
                DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 3.5) {
                  withAnimation() {
                    self.showSplash = false
                    splashDidFinish()
                  }
                }
            }

        }.onAppear {
            NSLog(".onAppear()")
        }
    }
    func splashDidFinish() {
        NotificationCenter.default.post(name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "checkApplicationReady"), object: nil)
    }
}
```

Comment: Try adding on your `ZStack {}.edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)`

Comment: No, same results

Comment: Please add a reproducible code !

Comment: Ahhh I think it's because of the way that ZStack() behaves. Try wrapping it in a `GeometryReader { reader in ZStack {...}.frame(x: reader.size.width, y: reader.size.height)`

Comment: Can you add code for `ContainerView` and `SplashView`?

Comment: @xTwisteDx usually you can just use `frame(maxWidth...)` instead of reading width and height values from `GeometryReader`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix it using:

```
    .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
```

Comment: What did you attach that too?

Comment: I attached that to ContentView